# What does $d\bar z$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

What does $d\bar z$ mean?

For a manifold, given a local coordinate, $dx$ acts on tangent vectors and gives its corresponding components.

What does $d\bar z$  do?

The complex field is a one dimensional complex manifold, given the standard coordinate $z$, what does $d\bar z$ even mean?

I saw this notation in some books when defining a metric tensor:

$$\lambda dz d\bar z\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

There is always some disagreement on such notation, but you should probably think of $dz$ as acting on tangent vectors (assuming we're in one dimension) by $dz(v) = v\in\Bbb C$ and $d\bar z$ as acting by $d\bar z(v) = \bar v$.  (In general, in working with complex manifolds, one works with the complexified tangent bundle, which is spanned by the "holomorphic" and "anti-holomorphic" vector fields.)

**EDIT**: Thanks to Jack. As I said, there is always disagreement and confusion (even among those of us who've worked in complex geometry). On one hand, we want $(dz\otimes d\bar z)(v,v)$ to mean $dz(v)\overline{dz(v)}=|v|^2$. But differentiating $\bar z = x - iy$, $d\bar z = dx - i\,dy$, we have $\overline{dz(v)} = d\bar z(\bar v)$. Ultimately, we need to decide whether we're computing the inner product by $(dz\otimes d\bar z)(v,v)$ or by $(dz\otimes d\bar z)(v,\bar v)$.  The occasional excellent and well-respected textbook gets these things muddled, too. As I said, confusing. I should never have weighed in :P

Comment: Since you're thinking of $v$ as a complexified tangent vector, your formulas aren't quite right.  You can write $v$ locally as $a \partial/\partial x + b\partial/\partial y$ for some complex constants $a,b$, and then $dz(v) = (dx + i\,dy)(v) = a+ib$, while $d\bar z(v) = (dx - i\,dy)(v) = a-ib\ne \overline{a+ib}$.

Answer (score 2):

$z$ is just the complex function on the complex plane and $\bar z$ is its conjugate. Writing in usual Euclidean coordinate, $z =x+ \sqrt{-1} y$ and $\bar z = x - \sqrt{-1} y$, so

$$dz =dx+ \sqrt{-1} dy \text{  and  } d\bar z = dx - \sqrt{-1} dy\ .$$

If you put this into the metric,

$$\lambda dzd\bar z = \lambda (dx dx + dydy)\ ,$$

which means that this is a very special expression: In general the first fundamental form has three unknown $E, F$ and $G$, but for this one you have $E=G = \lambda$ and $F=0$. Such a metric is called a conformal metric.

Comment: I think you mean $$\mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d}\bar{z} = -2\mathbf{i} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y $$

Comment: @Hurkyl: That depends on whether you think of the expression as a metric (symmetric tensor) or as a 2 form. If it is a two form then you are correct.

Comment: This is why it's *very* important to use $\wedge$ for exterior product!!