# Conjugation, $d\bar{z}$ and hermitian products

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

**Setting and Notation**

Let $(X,J)$ be an almost complex manifold $X$ of real dimension $2$ and let $TX$ be its (real) tangent bundle, let $TX_\mathbb{C}^* = Hom_\mathbb{C}(TX_\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ be the complex dual space of the complexified tangent space $TX_\mathbb{C}$. The probem is completely local so I could have took $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard structure.

If we define $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} := \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} := \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$ and $z = x + iy$ where $\{(x,y)\}$ are local charts for $X$, we have $dz = dx + i dy, \ d\bar{z} = dx - i dy$
and
$$
dz \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) = 1 ,\
dz \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \right) =0, \
d\bar z \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \right) = 1 ,\
d\bar z \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) =0.
$$

---

**The problem**

Let $\omega \in TX_\mathbb{C}^*$ be a 1-form. We might define the conjugate of $\omega$ in the following inequivalent ways:
$$\overline{\omega}(v) := \overline{\omega(v)} \quad \forall v \in TX_\mathbb{C} \tag{I}\label{I}$$
$$\widetilde{\omega}(v) := \overline{\omega(\overline{v})} \quad \forall v \in TX_\mathbb{C} \tag{II}\label{II}$$

Consider the standard hermitian product $h$ on $\mathbb{C}$.
We have:
$$h(v,w) = v \cdot  \overline{w} = dz(v) \cdot \overline{dz(w)} =: dz(v) \cdot \overline{dz}(w) = (dz \otimes \overline{dz})(v,w)$$
and hence we can write:
$$h = dz \otimes \overline{dz} \tag{HI}\label{HI}$$
but we **cannot** write:
$$h = dz \otimes d\overline{z} \tag{W}\label{W}$$
since
$$\overline{dz} \not = d\overline{z}$$
but instead
$$\overline{dz}(\overline{v}) = d\overline{z}(v) \tag{DZI}\label{DZI}$$
We can fix this by using the second definition $\eqref{II}$:
$$\widetilde{dz} = d\overline{z} \tag{DZII}\label{DZII}$$
But then we don't have a good notation to rewrite $\eqref{HI}$. Infact we can't drop the arguments since we need to conjugate the second one:
$$h(v,w) = v \cdot \overline{w} = dz(v) \cdot \overline{dz(w)} =: dz(v) \cdot \widetilde{dz}(\overline{w}) = (dz \otimes \widetilde{dz})(v,\overline{w}) = (dz \otimes d\overline{z})(v,\overline{w})$$

---

**Conclusion**

To sum it up, unless I am wrong, we have these 2 definitions, with the first $\eqref{I}$ we have a concise (and correct) way of writing, say, an hermitian product as in $\eqref{HI}$, but we do *not* have the familiar (?) equality $\overline{dz}=d\overline{z}$. By using the second definition $\eqref{II}$ we recover the equality $\eqref{DZII}$ but we loose a concise (and correct) way of writing a product.

Either way, writing $\eqref{W}$ is, in my opinion, wrong. Or maybe I am since is written like that almost everywhere.

Is this correct? Are there ways to make sense of formula $\eqref{W}$?

After spending 2 days unraveling all this I have to say I am a bit baffled by the fact that these notational inconsistencies are not usually dealt with or acknowledged better in texts.

Thanks a lot in advance

---

Related questions/anwers:
[What is $d\bar z$ as a form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763483/what-is-d-bar-z-as-a-form),
[What does $d\bar z$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757472/what-does-d-bar-z-mean)

Comment: Why do you think $\overline{dz} \neq d\bar{z}$?

Comment: See also the discussion in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885191/definition-of-dz-i-otimes-d-barz-j-frac-partial-partial-z-m-c-frac-part/2885936#2885936).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese If I take $v = a\frac{\partial}{\partial  z} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial  \overline{z}}$, then $d\overline{z}(v) = b$ but $\overline{dz(v)} = \overline{a}$

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, this definitely seems to help (at least to feel I am not going completely crazy). I need to think about it